# How to stop certain programs form suspending when the screen locks?

Tags: lock-screen

Is it possible to prevent some programs and scripts form suspending when the screen locks ?

Comment: Be more specific as to which programs and a sample script

Comment: Ehm. A screen lock does not suspend software. Suspending/hibernating does. And you probably have your system suspend when the screen is locked. If so stop doing that (see "power management").